# Partial order relation on $\mathcal{M}_{1,c}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}_{1,c}(\mathbb{R})$ the space of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support. There is a partial order relation on $\mathcal{M}_{1,c}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$\mu\succeq \nu \,\,\text{ if and only if }\int f d\mu \geq \int f d\nu \,\,\,\text{  for every bounded and increasing } f\in C(\mathbb{R}).$$
The point is that I don't understand why $f$ has to be increasing.

Reflexivity and transitivity are trivial; antisymmetry is true if and only if we prove that
$$\int f d\mu =\int f d\nu \,\,\,\text{  for every bounded and increasing } f\in C(\mathbb{R})\Longrightarrow \mu=\nu.$$
My question is: isn't this true if $f$ is just bounded and continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two distributions. Let $f$ be bounded and continuous and assume that $\int fd\nu\geq \int fd\mu$. Then the function $g=-f$ is also bounded and continuous and $$\int gd\nu =-\int fd\nu \leq -\int fd\mu = \int gd\mu.$$ Therefore it cannot be the case that $\int fd\nu\geq \int fd\mu$ for all bounded continuous functions.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, so the problem is with the definition itself?

Comment: Without the "increasing" it would be an equivalence relation, right?

Comment: @MathLover Correct. As my argument shows, if this relation holds for all bounded functions, then $\mu=\nu$. Equality is an equivalence relation, so yes. But as a "partial order" it is trivial.